# How to set automatic numbers of columns using all height of the screen estate on different devices in Windows 8 Store app?

Tags: css, layout, windows-store-apps, winjs, internet-explorer-10

**Using Javascript + HTML** for Windows 8 Store apps development, I'm looking for a simple way to have the layout of a page with some long content of text and a few images to typically 'automatically' adapt the number of columns of text in order for the user to **avoid having to scroll vertically** to read the text. I mean of course, to avoid "as much as possible" which means if the device is on landscape mode, the content will be spanned on columns, using vertically only the height available and adding as much columns as necessary.

If  I do something like this:

```
@media screen and (-ms-view-state: fullscreen-landscape)
{
    #main {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: -ms-grid;
        -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 300px;
        -ms-grid-rows: 132px 1fr;
    }
}
```

I always end up specifying ***only*** a 2 columns and 2 rows layout whether would have I used percents, fractions or pixels...

I guess on portrait mode it would usually feels more natural to still have one single column though, wouldn't it? But at least, for the *landscape* case, I'm not sure how to deal with it, because of the numerous types of screen dimensions of devices we find Windows 8 on.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You do know you're supposed to accept an answer if it solves your issue right @freeeman ? I've noticed you haven't accepted a single one so far. People will stop answering you eventually.

Comment: @TommyBs thanks, I was aware that people "accepted" answer on the site but was not sure if I got enough reputation to do so, or if several people had to upvote an answer to do so. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
I just realized that you're not looking for how to specify how many columns to display, but you're looking for tips on how to have your long content overflow into multiple columns.  Sorry about the misunderstanding.  My original answer below still addresses the issue of specifying how many columns are used in case that is needed.

There are some CSS rules for specifying columns (width, number of columns, gutter, etc.).  Used with a `height` rule, you can probably achieve what you're looking for.  Try something like this:

```
#main {
    column-count: auto;
    column-width: 200px;
    height: 360px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The MSDN article linked below discusses all of these options, but the IE "hands on" site will let you play around in real-time.

References:

- [MSDN article: Multi-column layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [IE "hands-on" site](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_multi-column.htm)

---

**Original answer:**

You could have different CSS based on width.  Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px) 
{
    #main {
        /* overrides for width less than 800 */
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:800px) and (max-width:1200px)
{
    #main {
        /* overrides for width between 800 and 1200 */
    }
}
```

References:

- [Metro: Understanding CSS Media Queries](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/02/29/metro-understanding-css-media-queries.aspx)
- [W3C: Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and updated one, I'm checking this out. This is very relevant to my interests ;)